# WebView with Video In a ViewPager keeps playing audio even after scrolling horizontally

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview

I have an `Activity` which has `ViewPager` containing a `WebView` which has `Text` and `Video`. When I play the video and press back the audio is still playing. Then I did

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(webView != null) {
        webView.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (webView != null) {
        webView.onResume();
    }
}
```

But when I swipe to next in the `ViewPager` new `url` is loading in the `WebView` but the audio is still playing from the previous `WebView`. Does anyone know the solution for this problem ?

EDIT:

## Solution

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (webView != null) {
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            webView.reload();
        } else {
            webView.onPause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try making your WebView global and static.

Comment: @DipeshDhakal making whole webview static is not a good practice.It can cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fragment's onPause() is not called as the fragment does not gets destroyed/paused (unless it is out of the offscreen limit) in a view pager.So you have to check if the fragment is visible or not.

You can do so by :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
//visible to user }

    else {  
//not visible

}
      }
    }
```

and then perform whatever operation you want with your webview.

Comment: @Logic can you please provide your code (like adapter and fragment)

Comment: @Logic what's the new issue.

Comment: when I move to next fragment in the viewpager i.e., in else condition of your code, I wrote webView.onPause(); audio is stopped. But when I come back play the video and then navigate to next one its not stopping the audio

Comment: it depends, count comes in JSON

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83709/discussion-between-anirudh-sharma-and-logic).

Comment: Did you solve the problem @AvinashRavilla. Can u please post the solution?

Comment: Hi, I faced the same problem and I use the above solution, it stop playing video but when return back or having two consecutive videos the video not play, please can help,My app do the same concept like you?!!

Answer (score 1):

you have to try

```
webView.destroy();
```

method may be it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add a onPageChangeListener to your viewpager.

```
/* in onViewCreated */
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //here get the webview of the previous page and do on pause.
        if (webview of prev page position is active)
          webview of perv position.onPause();
        //resume the webView if it was previously paused
        if (webView was previously paused )
           webView of position.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

You will have to fill in the algorithms.
Hope this helps

Comment: and don't forget to remove the listener. It wont really matter, but its good practice.